# Prevent screenshot in a single fragment android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, screenshot

I have an activity that contains some fragments in it, and I want to prevent screenshot in a single fragment only. But when I apply these codes to Fragment A

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activity?.window!!.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
```

the other fragments can't take screenshot too. Can we prevent screenshot only in one fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `clearFlag` once this fragment is no longer visible . i think this should work ..

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    activity?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}
```

Comment: this works good on me ! but I put the codes before `super.onDestroyView()`. Thanks mate